# Initializing new variables in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have built and trained a model. On second phase I want to replace the last two layers and retrain them using different data.
I constantly get the errors for not initializing variables even though I did run initialization on the new vars:

`var_init_op = tf.initialize_variables(var_list=[fc1_weights, fc1_biases, fc2_weights, fc2_biases])
sess.run(var_init_op)`

I understand I have to initialize the new optimizer (ADAMSolever) as well, but 
not sure how to do that.

Assuming I want to replace the optimizer (and other variables) in the middle how do I initialize it without trashing already trained variables?

Comment: Hi @dolbi, I am having a similar issue, even after initializing, it keeps telling me that it couldn't find the (new) variables in the ckpt file. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @RogerTrullo, sorry I ended up working around that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the trainable variables using tf.trainable_variables(), and exclude the variables which should be restored from the pretrained model. Then you can initialize the other variables.

Comment: initialize_variables is just a shortcut for "init_op for every Variable in GraphKeys.VARIABLES collection." If you want to initialize a subset of those variables, you'll need to construct this list yourself, like Sherry suggests